# How to update nested mongo object

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am trying to make a report function for my app

in the front end I make a put request :

```
.put(`http://localhost:3000/api/posts/report`, {
                        params: {
                            id: mongoId,
                            reportInfo: {
                                reported: true,
                                reportingUser: id
                            }
                        }
                    })
```

to this backend route

```
router.put('/report', (req, res, next) => {
    postModel.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.query.id) },
        req.query,
        { new: true, useFindAndModify: false },
        (error, returnedDocuments) => {
            if (error) return next(error);
            res.json(returnedDocuments);
        }
    );
});
```

for this model

```
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        title: { type: String },
        description: { type: String },
        image: { type: String },
        price: { type: String },
        location: { type: String },
        image: { type: Array },
        author: {
            type: String,
            ref: 'User'
        },
        reportInfo: {
            reported:{
                type: Boolean,
                default: false
            },

            reportingUser:{
            type: String
            }

        }
    },
    {
        timestamps: true
    }
);
```

any ideas why it is not updating the reportInfo object , do I need to do something if there are some nested objects contained?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code tries to replace entires MongoDB document. Try to use [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) instead of passing `req.query` directly:

```
{ $set: { reportInfo: req.query.reportInfo } }
```

I would also check if there should be `req.query` or `req.body` so just print the value to make sure that it gets deserialized properly.

Comment: yeah, its coming up as undefined... Is req.query only for certain type of requestS?

Comment: I used query to pass data for an axios delete object, so I'm not sure why its not good for a put req.

Comment: @jcx3x typically it should be passed as HTTP body and visible under `req.body` in nodejs